# Reading collection data succeeded and then throws error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

This is my `server.js`:

I'm trying to get the data by firstName and lastName,
then passing the data and log the firstName:

```
mongoDb.getFromDb(req.body.firstName, req.body.lastName)
  .then(
    rows => {
      rows.each(function(err, item) {
        console.log(item.firstName);
      })
    }
  )
});
```

`mongoDb.js`:

I have an init function that creates a promise that is called: `connectingDb`.
It connects to the DB.

```
// Use connect method to connect to the Server
function init() {
  connectingDb = new Promise(
    function(resolve, reject) {
      MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
          reject(err);
        } else {
          console.log('Connection established to', url);

          //Close connection
          //db.close();
          resolve(db);
        }
      });

    }
  );
}
```

This function gets first name and last name and returns the rows by those conditions.

```
function getFromDb(firstName, lastName) {
  return new Promise(
    function(resolve, reject) {
      connectingDb.then(myDb => {
        console.log('a1a1a1');

        resolve(myDb.collection('alon').find({
          "firstName": firstName,
          "lastName": lastName
        }));

      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
    }

  )
}
```

And this is the data when I write it in `mongodb powershell':

[the data of the collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbher.png)

The error is:

```
a
D:\Search\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:98
   process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of null
```

While `a` is the first name..

I guess the function `mongoDb.getFromDb` is called twice because of the promise.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should `rows` maybe changed to `item` within `rows.each`?
That is, instead of

```
...
  rows.each(function(err, item) {
    console.log(rows.firstName);
  })
...
```

more something like

```
...
  rows.each(function(err, item) {
    console.log(item.firstName);
  })
...
```

---

Update: In addition you probably want to use [forEach](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/#cursor.forEach) instead of `each` like so

```
getFromDb(firstName, lastName)
  .then(
    rows => {
      rows.forEach(function(item) {      
        console.log(item.firstName);
      })
    }
  );
```

Comment: Sorry, my fault.
I saw it after I posted the post and changed it, but I get the same error (I restart the server)..

Comment: Yes, it works! I will read the difference between each to forEach..
Thank you very much!